# Numeric Keyboard on close opens Alphanumeric keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am using `inputType:number` for EditText.

But the problem is that when I click on Done Button(Right Mark) present at bottom left of keyboard it opens up Alphanumeric keyboard.

My EDIT TEXT XML Code:

```
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:id="@+id/enter_detail"
        android:hint="Enter Detail"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColorHint="#42a5f5"
        android:textColor="@color/title_black"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/radio_group"/>
```

**UPDATE**
I have found that `DATEPICKER` with datePickerMode="spinner" is creating issue.

I switched to `datePickerMode="calendar"` and it solved the problem.

I think there is a problem with the DatePicker widget because when used `spinner` mode bottom part is incomplete(Please refer to this question to understand this problem: [Android: Datepicker bottom part not visbile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54638584))

I have created GIF of the video:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

How about replacing the inputType with "number|numberDecimal"

android:inputType="number|numberDecimal".

Comment: Please also check if number or number decimal are the only checked input type. All the rest must be unchecked. Thanks.